# GoogleEarth inside Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, google-earth

Is it possible to embed a GoogleEarth view inside a Java Swing app?  If so, could you please point me to a tutorial explaining how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embedding GoogleEarth inside Java Swing App is not feasible. Legally or otherwise. However you may find a way to embed Google Map on a frame.

Edit: Found this [google post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/08/java-support-and-docs-for-maps-data-api.html).

Comment: The Google post was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There's also NASA's [World Wind SDK](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Even though technically it is possible (using JXMapViewer), legaly it is not. Google does not allow using Google Maps outside of the browser.

One possible solution would be to embed JWebPane (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alex2d/archive/JWebPaneJ1.pdf) into your Swing App, but it is still not ready :(

Answer (score 2):

I did a project on vehicle tracking system using GPS and GSM at my college.
In the project we used to get the latitude and longitude value of vehicle and show it in Google map.
The code we used for creating a frame with Google location is [Map code.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99420873/JGoogleMapEditorPan.java)

The frame is created by creating an Object of the class and calling the method

`createmap(String x,String y);`

Where, x-latitude and y-longitude.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a link on java.net ...

[Building Maps into Your Swing Application with the JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lil' tutorial which explains it all:

http://www.brantb.com/2007/12/java-and-google-earth-com-api.html

It uses the Google Earth COM API

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jawin to extract native stubs and use it to embed Google Earth on a Java Swing container. I've worked on it before, please check my demo video on youtube

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Pf8V8uubVM

As WTP'-- pointed out to the Blog, http://www.brantb.com/2007/12/java-and-google-earth-com-api.html Brant used "com4J" to generate the stubs.

Answer (score -1):

you could us a java RDP client and run Google Earth on a remote desktop