# Working in java image

Tags: java, image, graphics, dictionary, zooming

I will explain my question clearly. 
  I need to zoom in/zoom out the world map.
  When I click on the particular country in map, control should redirected to new page with respective the country.
  I dont have any idea about this in java. Please explain the steps to acheive the above task.

Comment: Please tell us which technique you are using, what exactly you want to zooooom and what countries you talk about. :)

Comment: Do you use a single image which should be zoomed (will get blurry) or do you have several images each of them with different zoom levels?

Answer (score 0):

As the question is quite general, here is a general answer: Zooming often means, that you want to display a certain percentage of somethin, and not the whole, where your size of the displayed will not change.

But in your case it seems more like a "find a mouse click in a polygon" thing. So you have to add a selection/click listener to whatever widgets you use (Swt? swing? ....?) where you change what your program renders.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to reinvent the wheel. Google etc have already solved this problem rather well. It might be better to incorporate an existing solution into your application. Have a look at [GoogleEarth inside Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303333/googleearth-inside-java-swing).