# Launching Google Earth using Java swing

Tags: java, swing, google-earth

Can someone please help me how to launch Google Earth application using Java swing? (I mean on click of the GUI button it should open the Google Earth application)

Comment: Duplicated:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303333/googleearth-inside-java-swing

Comment: @Tirma It is not a valid duplicate please compare the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
try {
    File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.exe");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // no application registered for PDFs
}
}
```

Or by Another Way

```
  try{

    if ((new File("c:\\your_file.exe")).exists()) {

        Process p = Runtime
           .getRuntime()
           .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\\your_file.exe");
        p.waitFor();

    } else {

        System.out.println("File does not exist");

    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```